# ABR - frames repeating while playing

Tags: android

I'm using Adaptive Bitrate Streaming contents (ABR) for playing in android.Some time's facing problem that some frames are repeating and some frames are missing.

If it continuously playing same profile then this problem is not there.while shifting from one bit rate profile to  other this problem occurs.

Please some one help me to find out the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for my problem.

Problem was with ABR contents. Contents which I was using are not well GOP aligned, this was creating problem when profiles are changing.